# TeamCity and cppcheck output template

Tags: teamcity, cppcheck

I run cppcheck on my code in TeamCity and want to report its errors as build problems. So I changed the cppcheck output format to

```
"##teamcity[buildProblem\tdescription='{file}({line}):\t{severity}:\t{message}']"
```

The general idea is OK. But the problem is that some of the messages contain the character ' and this causes an error in parsing the output becasue TeamCity requires escaping apostrophes. For example, here's an excerpt from my build log:

```
[17:20:05][Step 2/2] Checking ..\..\..\services_package\Services\FaultsManager\FaultsManager.c...
[17:20:14][Step 2/2] ##teamcity[buildProblem    description='..\..\..\services_package\Services\FaultsManager\FaultsManager.c(83):  style:  The scope of the variable 'channelID' can be reduced.']
[17:20:15]
[Step 2/2] Property value not found
Valid property list format is (name( )*=( )*'escaped_value'( )*)* where escape symbol is "|"
[17:20:14][Step 2/2] ##teamcity[buildProblem description='..\..\..\services_package\Services\FaultsManager\CommonDef.h(32): warning:    Redundant code: Found a statement that begins with numeric constant.']
```

The second error gets reported but the first doesn't. I think it's becasue the first contains 'channelID' and this confuses the parser.

How can I get TeamCity to display the error messages nicely? Obviously I can get it to fail the build if the analysis fails but I want the overview page to display meaningful data - number of errors, number of new ones, the list of errors, etc. (similaly to failed tests).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a script which post-processes the output: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/dinazil/2015/08/31/more-on-code-quality/

Comment: It would be great if you could move main insights from external link into the post for the sake of keeping it reproducible in the future.

Comment: @Dina this is broken link now.

Comment: I think I may have found Dinas link on github https://github.com/dinazil/blogsamples/blob/master/teamcity_and_cppcheck/run_cppcheck.py

Answer (score 3):

There is also another possibility that I wrote about in [my blog post in Russian](https://roman.khimov.ru/2018/04/11/cppcheck-teamcity/). You can use [Teamcity XML report processing](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/XML+Report+Processing) and all of its associated functionality ("Code Inspection" tab, metrics, automated changes tracking), but you need to convert cppcheck's XML output into something Teamcity understands. I've used XSLT for that:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml"></xsl:output>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <checkstyle>
    <xsl:attribute name="version">
      <xsl:value-of select="results/cppcheck[@version]"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="results/errors/error" group-by="(location/@file)[1]">
      <file>
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
          <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
          <error line="{(location/@line)[1]}" message="{@msg}" severity="{@severity}" source="{@id}" />
        </xsl:for-each>
      </file>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </checkstyle>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which produces Checkstyle XML. It's used like this:

```
$ cppcheck --enable=all --xml --xml-version=2 . 2>cppcheck-report.xml
$ saxonb-xslt cppcheck-report.xml cppcheck-2-to-checkstyle.xslt >cppcheck-checkstyle.xml
```

Teamcity configuration to process the resulting XML:

[image: Teamcity XML report processing setup]

Integrating cppcheck this way has some advantages (aside from "Code Inspection" tab that just has a better interface than plain log line) in that you're in a better control of the build behaviour. Using "buildProblem" you're failing the build and that probably is OK when you're dealing with a tightly controlled small clean codebase, but it certainly is not when you're working on some kind of huge legacy codebase that has thousands of warnings (fixing all of them is just way too expensive and cppcheck also has false positives). It allows you to make some rules like "warning/error counters should not increase" and easily catch new problems, like this:

[image: Teamcity build failure setup]

Notice that it uses "latest successful build" as a reference point so that if someone fixes some old problem you have new (lower) reference counts that successive builds will be compared against.

Comment: For some errors Cppcheck generates multiple line/file entries. This leads to same error reported multiple times and to concatenated line numbers, e.g., `line="123 345"`. We fixed it by modifying XSLT  to only use a first entry of each error: `group-by="(location/@file)[1]"`, `line="{(location/@line)[1]}"`

Comment: @AMA: I had some fixes to this XSLT, but I don't quite remember which ones and these days I'm not using Teamcity at all, so it would be hard for me to check anything related to it. Feel free to edit the post to fix it, I'll approve the changes.

Comment: Done (no approval was needed, hehe)

Comment: @AMA do you have a sample of the input and output to share ?   I think i could just translate this to python if i knew what i was lookin at. Because that tool is not free for use.